# Node Redis keeps calling error function if Redis is down

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm using node redis and in server.js I have something like:

```
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function(error) {
  console.log("error");
});
```

in the console, if the redis server is down it will repeatedly call that function forever. So the output of my program is

```
error
error
error
error
...
```

Is there any way to make this just call it once? My redis db isn't always on. When it's off I just want to know about that error once.

Comment: The error is shown every time the client tries to establish a connection and failed to do so. You can disable the "retryStrategy" - but I don't think you actually wanna do it.
https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis/tree/v3.1#rediscreateclient

Answer (score 1):

The workaround would be to keep the state of the redis on the server. Something like this:

```
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();

var redisUp = true

// I have no idea if the right event is "connect" or "ready", but "connect" seems more logical
client.on("connect", function() {
  redisUp = true;
});

client.on("error", function(error) {
  if(redisUp) {
    redisUp = false;
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```